# Spring Data postgresql 10 insertion does not work

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am working on spring boot application with *RestController*, *Service* a *Repository* and an Entity.

My problem is when I call the web service to save my data in the data base, it seems it works fine and there is no exception thrown but when I check my data base I find that the table was created but I find no data saved. and here is what I get in the output(for each element in my list):

> Hibernate: 
>       insert 
>       into
>           table_name
>           (columnOne, columnTwo) 
>       values
>           (?, ?)

Here is my code:

*RestController*:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/")
public class myController {

     @Autowired
     private MyService myService;

  @PostMapping(path="/inject/{year}")
    public void myControllerMethod(@PathParam("year") Year year) {
        this.myService.myServiceMethod(year);
    }
}
```

*Service*:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

@Autowired
MyRepository myRepository;

public void myServiceMethod(Year year) {
    List<MyEntity> myEntityList = this.parseMyEntityList(year);
    this.myRepository.save(myEntityList)
  }
}
```

*Repository*:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<InseeLibelle> {
}
```

*Entity*:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "columnOne_idx", columnList = "columnOne"),
        @Index(name = "columneTwo_idx", columnList = "columnTwo"),
})

public class MyEntity{

@JsonIgnore
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long columnId;

@Column
private Integer columnOne;

@Column
private String columnTwo;

 public Integer getColumnOne() {
    return columnOne;
}

public void setColumnOne(Integer columnOne) {
    this.columneOne = colmunOne;
}

public String getColumnTwo() {
    return columnTwo;
}

public void setColumnTwo(String columnTwo) {
    this.columnTwo = columnTwo;
}
}
```

I tried to add this line in the repository but it does not work too:

```
<S extends MyEntity> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) ;
```

Comment: Please post your table definition and stacktrace if any

Comment: finally the problem was with pgAdmin (I have checked the data  from pgAdmin and I get nothing, it seems there is a problem with it), I have made findAll in the code and I have found my data well persited,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is with the pgAdmin (like my case), it does not show the data but they exist in the database, try **findAll** method in the repository or check them with **select *** directly.